# How do you clear a UIWebView's cache?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Essentially, I need to know how to make a UIWebView erase everything when you terminate the app. Basically, that includes all cookies and information held by the webView through usage.

Is there any way to simply clear it so that it's like new each time?

Comment: good question... I'm editing your question to remove the Xcode tag and the word from the title as this question has absolutely nothing to do with the IDE but with iOS & UIWebView.

Comment: What do you mean by "when you terminate the app"? When it moves to the background?

Comment: Yeah, I just need the information for removing everything that it keeps track of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIWebView` doesn't cache, it's the `NSURLConnection` it uses. Any of the following used to work, and follows the documentation of `NSURLCache`:

```
// remove all cached responses
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

// set an empty cache
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

// remove the cache for a particular request
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

But I'm not sure if it does now (iOS 5). Other options are using a custom cache: [SDURLCache](https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache) or [overriding connection:withCacheResponse:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). If you find out what is the current behavior please comment.

Comment: First one and third one compile when you just throw them in there. However, the second doesn't seem to work, throwing the error "initializer Element is not a compile time constant". I'm not sure, but do you know how to solve that problem? Perhaps I'm setting it in the wrong place?

Comment: Perhaps that isn't all I need. Google keeps track of things, and I was hoping clearing cookies and such would erase the search history and whatnot. It's just for experimentation.